# Traefik : do not obfuscate HTTP bodywith code >400

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

Is there a way to tell Traefik not overwrite the response body when the response code is `> 400`  ?

The goal is to keep the body of a 404 or a 401 response
The goal is not have a custom error page but the real error page from the backend.

The environment is a Kubernetes Cluster where Traefik is the ingress provider, the storage used by traefik is consul.

Comment: Have you looked at `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/error-pages: <YML>` [annotation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#general-annotations)?

Comment: yup, really need the application error page, not another error page, and when setting the backend, same as the host, it fails, arning for an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer my question : https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4114
this is not possible since the net/http golang lib is implementing the [RFC 7230  sec. 3.1.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)  hardly,
and does not plan to change it.